# Problems with Ajax on xampp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i have a problem i was using usbwebserver for my localhost but i had to switch to xampp because of php 5.5. But now is one of my functions misbehaving. It shows only 2/6 pictures from directory and i don't know why. It's function that will add an image to my body when clicked on that image. No errors on page found.

```
  var pom = document.getElementById("ImageAdd");
  pom.style.visibility = "visible";
  var dir = "uploads";
  var fileextension = [".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".gif"];
  $.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < fileextension.length; i++) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension[i] + ")").each(function() {
          var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
          $("#ImageAdd").append("<img src=\"" + dir + filename + "\" onclick=\"addimg('" + dir + filename + "')\">");
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Does the console returns any errors? Because this is javascript ;p